# display another div after form submit goes wrong

Tags: jquery, function, hide, show

I have 2 sections, first is a form which is displayed standard

```
<section id="formulier" style="display:">
   <h3>Welkom op mijn pagina, vul de gegevens in om mijn motivatiebrief te kunnen zien.</h3>
     <form class="formulier-gegevens" name="form" id="form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="document.getElementById('formulier').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('brief').style.display = '';">
       <input type="text" name="voornaam" class="formulier-input" placeholder="Vul uw voornaam in" required>
       <input type="text" name="tussenvoegsels" class="formulier-input" placeholder="Vul uw tussenvoegsel(s) in">
       <input type="text" name="achternaam" class="formulier-input" placeholder="Vul uw achternaam in" required>
       <input class="verzend btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Verstuur">
     </form>
  </section>
```

I want to `display:none` this section after the form submit and I want to display this section

```
<section id="brief" style="display:none">
  <h3>Hier komt de motivatiebrief </h3>

  Hey daar <?php echo $voornaam , " ", $tussenvoegsels, " ",  " ", $achternaam; ?>!

  </section>
```

But as soon as I submit the form, you can see the second section for a second, then it goes back to `display:none` again and the first section is displayed again.

currently I have `onsubmit="document.getElementById('formulier').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('brief').style.display = '';"` on my form.
And I also tried to use a function with hide and show:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
        $("#formulier").hide();
        $("#brief").show();
    });
});`

but without any success, what causes this split second show of the section?
And how can I fix this?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you trying to show/hide sections if the form submit is unsuccessful?

Comment: no, I want to show/hide sections when the form is submitted correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting executed but the page is also getting refreshed which is why you see the result for a split second.

If you submit a form it will redirect to the url of the action parameter. When there is no action parameter the page will refresh.

You can prevent the page from refreshing by preventing the form to be actually send.

Replace this line `$('#form').submit(function(e) {` With the lines below:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: But I also want to get the value of the inputs, will this still be possible after I use this code?

Comment: I would like to use PHP instead

Comment: You can show the values of the inputs with jQuery. For example something like `$("#brief").append($("input[name=voornaam]").val());`  Using PHP won't work because that needs to be handled server-side. If you want to use PHP you have to show or hide the sections with a PHP if statement instead of using jQuery. (maybe this answer will clear things up a bit: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/171210)

Comment: Allright and how can I display the values on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Use session.
if you submit the the form. make a session with a false value.
put it inside an input.

```
<input type="text" value="false" id='input'>
```

$session['check'] = "".$('#input').val()."";
during submission
you just check your desired validation for your form. if the the user input a  correct data. then set the input value to true;$('#input').val(true)"
and check this is your code in the main index.
if($session['check']){

$css = 'style='display:none/block';

}`<section $css class='section1'></section>
<section $css class='section2'></section>`